# I am having issues compiling my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Tags: bibliographies, compiling, compilation-error

My school gave me a latex template to follow and for the last few weeks have had no issues compiling or running anything. However, I have recently run into an error that I can not seem to fix. This is the error message:

> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.  ...rline {5}\begin
>   {thebibliography}{}}
>                                                     \hyper@linkend  l.14 ...begin {thebibliography}{}}{11}{section*.2}
>                                                     %

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$`. But perhaps the `}` is legitimate and you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}`. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}`.

> ! pdfTeX error (ext1): \pdfendlink cannot be used in vertical mode.
>   \close@pdflink ...\Hy@VerboseLinkStop \pdfendlink

and here is the code that I was working on when it stopped compiling.

```
\newpage

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{notes}
(2020). Lab 1 Measurements and Error Analysis
[Word Document]. Retrieved from
\texttt{https://famu-fsu-eng.instructure.com/courses/3039/files/
104226module$_$item$_$id=23826}

\bibitem{notes}
(2020). Lecture 1 Measurements and Uncertainties (Errors)
[Word Document]. Retrieved from
\texttt{https://famu-fsu-eng.instructure.com/courses/3039/files/
106209?module$_$item$_$id=25771}

\bibitem{notes}
(2020). Lecture 2: Error Propagation and Statistical Analysis
[Word Document]. Retrieved from
\texttt{https://famu-fsu-eng.instructure.com/courses/3039/files/
108691?module$_$item$_$id=26696}

\bibitem{notes}
(2020). Lecture 3: Statistical Analysis of Experimental Data
[Word Document]. Retrieved from
\texttt{https://famu-fsu-eng.instructure.com/courses/3039/files/
109454?module$_$item$_$id=26850}

\end{thebibliography}
```

I have actually tried deleting all of the bibliography code but it still wont recompile. Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Welcome! Does replacing `\begin{thebibliography}{}` by `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` help?

Comment: What about loading the `url` pacakge and then use `\url{http://...}` removing the `$` for the links to the webisites?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the OP uses `$_$` to trying to escape the underscore character. In  LaTeX `_` is the instruction to print a subscript. The underscore `_` can be obtained by the command `\_`. A better solution is to load the `url` package, and then use

```
\url{http://...}
```

for the links to the websites.

So an MWE should look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{notes1}
(2020). Lab 1 Measurements and Error Analysis
[Word Document]. Retrieved from
\texttt{https://famu-fsu-eng.instructure.com/courses/3039/files/
104226module\_item\_id=23826}

\bibitem{notes2}
(2020). Lecture 1 Measurements and Uncertainties (Errors)
[Word Document]. Retrieved from
\url{https://famu-fsu-eng.instructure.com/courses/3039/files/
106209?module_item_id=25771}

\end{thebibliography}  
\end{document}
```

In the first example (not recommended) the underscore are escaped by the proper command `\_`.  In the second example, the link is wrapped in a `\url{}` command (the advantage would be that the URL can be broken across lines.

By the way, all your `\bibitem`s have the same label (`notes`). While this is not a problem for the question, you cannot use them to call and differentiate the references in the document.